# Setting specific colors in chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot this data with ggplot2. Below you can see my data and code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Sample data frame (replace this with your actual dataset)
data <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  Column2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
  Column3 = c(9, 10, 11, 12),
  Column4 = c(13, 14, 15, 16)
)

# Calculate cumulative sums for each column
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    Cumulative_Column1 = cumsum(Column1),
    Cumulative_Column2 = cumsum(Column2),
    Cumulative_Column3 = cumsum(Column3),
    Cumulative_Column4 = cumsum(Column4))
```

Now I am trying to plot this data with code below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Column1)) +
          geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column1, fill = "Cumulative_Column1"), alpha = 0.3) +
          geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column2, fill = "Cumulative_Column2"), alpha = 0.3) +
          geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column3, fill = "Cumulative_Column3"), alpha = 0.3) +
          geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column4, fill = "Cumulative_Column4"), alpha = 0.3) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c(
            "Cumulative_Column1" = "red",
            "Cumulative_Column2" = "blue",
            "Cumulative_Column3" = "green",
            "Cumulative_Column4" = "purple"
          )) +
          labs(
            x = " ",
            y = "Cumulative Sum",
            title = "",
            caption = "Source:"
          ) +
          theme_minimal()
```

This code give me the plot as plot shown below:

[image]

So the colors in the charts and colors in the legend are not the same.

Can any body help me how to solve this problem and to have same colors as the colors from the legend ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does plot the colors, but because of transparency and multiple overlapping colors it looks different. You could fix this by swapping the order of plotting the colors to prevent overlapping transparency. You also then don't need an `alpha` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Column1)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column4, fill = "Cumulative_Column4")) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column3, fill = "Cumulative_Column3")) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column2, fill = "Cumulative_Column2")) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Cumulative_Column1, fill = "Cumulative_Column1")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Cumulative_Column1" = "red",
    "Cumulative_Column2" = "blue",
    "Cumulative_Column3" = "green",
    "Cumulative_Column4" = "purple"
  )) +
  labs(
    x = " ",
    y = "Cumulative Sum",
    title = "",
    caption = "Source:"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: +1 The order of plotting will prevent from overlapping colors. With previous order, only the purple would have been displayed